# how to play audio instead of showing wintext when puzzle has been completed

Tags: unity-game-engine

Currently my code displays a YOU WIN text when the player fully matches all puzzle pieces. I want to change it to having an audio played when the player finishes the puzzle.

```
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform[] pictures;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject winText;

    public static bool youWin;

  void Start()
    {
       winText.SetActive = (false);
        youWin = false;
    }



void Update()
        {
            if(pictures[0].rotation.z == 0 &&
                pictures[1].rotation.z == 0 &&
                pictures[2].rotation.z == 0 &&
                pictures[3].rotation.z == 0 &&
                pictures[4].rotation.z == 0 &&
                pictures[5].rotation.z == 0 )

            {

                winText.SetActive = (true);
                  youWin = true;

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you'll need a few things.

1. An audio source attached to your object or to an object known to your script.
2. An audioclip, an audio that the audiosource can play. Can be already in your audio source.
3. If your audio source is attached to the same GameObject as your script you can do something like this, inside a function:

   ```
   AudioSource audioSource = GetComponent <AudioSource> ();
   audioSource.Play ();
   ```
4. You could also have a public field with a specific sound and call it different:

   ```
   AudioSource audioSource = GetComponent <AudioSource> ();
   audioSource.PlayOneShot (audioClip);
   ```

   And in the class you'd need a:

   ```
   public AudioClip audioClip;
   ```

But please, read Unity documentation, is all there.